# kineticjs object toJSON and back again to object

Tags: javascript, oop, kineticjs

Im still learning JS and I've been trying to make an app using KineticJS but keeping it in an object oriented way.

So I have something like:

```
/*   ClassA Constructor   */
    var ClassA=function(id, x, y, name, layer){
        this.id=id;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.name=name;
        this.layer=layer;

        this.object_group=new Kinetic.Group({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            id: id,
            draggable: true,
            name: "A_object_group"
        });

        var object_polygon=new Kinetic.Polygon({
            points: [0,0,1,1],
            fill: '#ffffff',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            opacity: 0.5,
            name: "A_object_polygon"
        });

        this.object_group.methodA=function(){
            //Method A goes here
        };

        this.object_group.add(object_polygon);
        this.layer.add(this.object_group);

    return(this.object_group);
}
```

Then I will convert the stage to JSON by using KineticJS method toJSON(), and later load it again from JSON using the Kinetic.Node.create() method.

It is all working fine, the problem is that after loading the objects they will not recognize the "MethodA" defined in the "ClassA" Class.

Im not sure whether or not this is the best approach, maybe I should be serializing the whole object to JSON and not only the Kinetic.Group part. Also, serializing a method doesnt seem to be a valid approach either, so the question: How can I load KineticJS objects from JSON and make them still belong to a class and allow the access to that class's methods?

Comment: Function definitions cannot be part of a JSON String (most converters will simply omit them) as JSON is supposed to be a pure data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

1. Add an attribute to the group which identifies it as a member of classA, let say `this.object_group.setAttribute('class','ClassA')`
   This attribute is saved in the JSON string.
2. When creating the node back from JSON, once the stage is all set, search the layer for all objects which have attribute 'class' set to 'ClassA' and reassign the function to these objects.

The method works fine if you do not have to recreate objects too often.

Alternately: You can assign all such objects a same name say `objClassA` and then use `layer.get(".objClassA")` [(see doc here)](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#get) which returns a collection of objects with the given name and then iterate through them to add back the function

Answer (score 0):

Well to solve this, I had to change the way I was defining methodA. 
Instead of:

```
this.object_group.methodA=function(){
    //Method A goes here
};
```

I used `prototype` to define methodA outside of the class constructor

```
/*   ClassA Constructor   */
var ClassA=function(id, x, y, name, layer){
    this.id=id;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.name=name;
    this.layer=layer;

    this.object_group=new Kinetic.Group({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        id: id,
        draggable: true,
        name: "A_object_group"
    });

    var object_polygon=new Kinetic.Polygon({
        points: [0,0,1,1],
        fill: '#ffffff',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        opacity: 0.5,
        name: "A_object_polygon"
    });

    this.object_group.methodA=ClassA.prototype.methodA;

    this.object_group.add(object_polygon);
    this.layer.add(this.object_group);

return(this.object_group);
},

ClassA.prototype={
    methodA: function(){
        //Method A goes here
    }
};
```

And finally, when I loaded KineticJS JSON I just had to reassign methodA this way:

```
stage.destroy();
stage=Kinetic.Node.create(kineticjs_json, canvas_container);
if(stage.get(".A_object_group")[0]){
    stage.get(".A_object_group")[0].methodA=ClassA.prototype.methodA;
}
```